# Audio file throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android

I've read any single question here but none of them solved my problem. I'm trying to play a media file but it says:

> E/MediaPlayer(554): prepareAsync called in state 8 W/System.err(554):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException W/System.err(554): at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

I couldn't find out where the problem is.. Works(throws exception) on emulator, force closes on tablet. I've seen a post says I shouldn't use prepare method but if I don't nothing changes.

Here is code & errors:

```
 MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MyAct.this, R.raw.zboo);
        player.setLooping(false); 

        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.start();
```

> E/MediaPlayer(522): prepareAsync called in state 8
>
> W/System.err(554): java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> W/System.err(554):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native
>   Method)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First you don't need to call prepare() as this is done by create anyway.
From Android documentation;

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

Secondly if the situation requites that you need to prepare then use prepareAsync() instead, otherwise the UI can hang. Asynchronous preparation does the preparation part on a background thread and returns the results when done. [Android documentation has more on this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Check your media file to make sure that it is playable.

Comment: Thanks! it turned out my file is not playable :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. When I write this four methods one by one instead of putting some logic(code) in between this four line and it was solved.

```
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("songpath");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

> you want to write mp.reset()   before calling of mp.prepare() And all the method call one bye one line